# Login into Youtube Account using automation tools like Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-signin

I am trying to automate logging into Youtube and press a button on my YouTube Studio profile. It is something I do everyday and can't be automated via API.

I am trying to login to my Google account using Selenium but it does not work since it complains that the "browser cannot be trusted". I am exploring what options are available.
Would it be possible to:

- bypass this restriction and use another user-agent? I also tried the `undetected chrome driver` https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver but it still gives me the same error
- if I use a paid cloud service to run the browser like https://browerless.io/ would I hit the same blocker?
- would there be a possibility to use my login cookies to use selenium on an already logged in browser session? How would the expiration work?

Comment: You should be able to create a new profile manually and log that in manually.  Then set your driver options to use that already created profile.  (however, Google may still block you because of bot detection... not real sure.)